# Elixir list pattern matching ~ get x after constant with list pattern matching

Tags: linked-list, erlang, pattern-matching, elixir

Does Elixir handle matching values relative to constants in any way?
An example of this would be ::

*All the examples are a pseudo syntax for the idea*

- **(the value after) 3 = x**
- iex> `[ _ | [ 3 | [ x | _ ] ] ] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // x = 4`
- **(the value before 6) = x**
- iex> `[ _ | [ x | [ 6 | _ ] ] ] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // x = 5`
- **(the sublist of values between 3 and 6) = x**
- iex> `[ _ | [ 3 | [ x | [ 6 | _ ] ] ] ] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // x = [4,5]`
- **(the sublist of the 3 values after 4) = [a,b,c]**
- iex> `[ _ | [ 3 | [ [a,b,c] | _ ] ] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // x = [5,6,7]`

Unfortunately most books and online documentation only covers absolute positioning from the first index, such as N elements from the head via `[ head | tail ]` but as the target value gets farther from the first element this becomes kinda silly with syntax like `[ _ | [ _ | [ _ | [ x | _ ] ] ] ]` to get the 4th element in a list.

Is there any syntax for matching relative indexes of a list? An example of incorrect but conceptually plausible syntax  would be getting the last index in a list via `[ _ | [ x | [] ] ]` or getting the value after the index of 3 via `[ _ | [ 3 | [ x | _ ] ] ]`

Comment: Please provide the example input and the expected output, It’s really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is that clearer with the expected outputs? I am fully aware this code is not valid but should demonstrate the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Elixir/Erlang do not support pattern matching an item at an unknown position in a list, so none of the 4 cases you mentioned can be done with pattern matching.

The only thing that can be simplified is where you want the 4th element of a list. Instead of:

```
[_ | [_ | [_ | [x | _]]]]
```

you can use the pattern:

```
[_, _, _, x | _]
```

```
iex(1)> [_, _, _, x | _] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
iex(2)> x
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing pattern matching as it is known in Elixir. When you are interested in *finding* values across the list, there is *no pattern*.

— (the value after) 3 = x

```
iex> [_, x | _] = Enum.drop_while([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], fn e -> e != 3 end)
#⇒ x = 4
```

— (the value before 6) = x

```
iex> [x | _] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
...> |> Enum.take_while(fn e -> e != 6 end)
...> |> Enum.reverse
#⇒ x = 5
```

— (the sublist of values between 3 and 6) = x

```
iex> [_ | x] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
...> |> Enum.drop_while(fn e -> e != 3 end)
...> |> Enum.take_while(fn e -> e != 6 end)
#⇒ x = [4, 5]
```

— (the sublist of the 3 values after 4) = [a,b,c]

```
iex> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
...> Enum.drop_while(fn e -> e != 4 end)
...> Enum.slice(1..3)
#⇒ [5,6,7]
```

[`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html).

Comment: I wouldn't call it abusing pattern matching per se. The idea of pattern matching is not restricted to fix position patterns.